# Sql query for Getting count with mutilple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to get count of times that fall between the break times.

There are 3 breaks with start as `break1_start , break2_start , break3_start` and end as `break1_end , break2_end and break3_end`.

I have to check wether the start time of time selected is before the break time and its endtime  is  within the breaktime

This the query i am using but it gives an sql error after the first 'AND'.

```
SELECT count(*) as end 
FROM vendor 
WHERE vendor_id = '31' 
AND (
     (break1_start > '10:15:0'  AND break1_end > '11:15') 
     or (break2_start > '10:15:0'  AND break2_end > '11:15') 
     or (break3_start > '10:15:0'  AND break3_end > '11:15')
);
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: BTW, maybe your break*_end should be `< 11:15`

Comment: Sorry guys it was just a errror of wrong values being assigned.thanx for ur help

Comment: what datatype are the break fields ?

Comment: NP, you can still delete your question :)